# Count and data in single query in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions-runtime

I want to return the count and data by writing it in a single Cosmos sql query.

Something like

```
Select *, count() from c
```

Or if possible i want get the count in a json document.

```
[
    {
        "Count" : 1111
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jon",
        "Age" : 30
    }
]
```

Comment: I think it's better to count the response items in your code, and in my opinion, the best result you can get from query result is like [ {"id" : "1", "count" : 3}, { "id" : "2" , "count" : 3}, 
 {"id" : "3" , "count" : 3}]

Comment: Data size is huge,so thats not an option. I am planning to use count to help with offset and limit.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to issue two separate queries - one to get the total number of documents matching your query, and a second to get a page of documents.